# jenkins remoting callable on slave using groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-scriptler

I was trying the remoting code to communicate with a jenkins node via the groovy shell. Here is the bare code which I ran:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.lang.String;
    import hudson.remoting.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;        

    Callable<String, IOException> task = new Callable<String, IOException>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws IOException {
            // This code will run on the build slave
            return "Testing";
        }
        @Override
        public void checkRoles(org.jenkinsci.remoting.RoleChecker checker)
          throws SecurityException {
            // nothing to do here
        }
        @Override
        private void readObject(ObjectInputStream aInputStream)
          throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
             aInputStream.defaultReadObject();
        }

        private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream aOutputStream)
          throws IOException {
            aOutputStream.defaultWriteObject();
        }
    };
    // Get a "channel" to the build machine and run the task there
    String hostname = Jenkins.getInstance().slaves
      .find({it.name == 'testNode'}).getComputer().getChannel().call(task);
```

Upon running the above script I see the following exception trace:

```
  java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize Script1$1@1aa0c77
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:169)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.<init>(UserRequest.java:63)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:751)
        at hudson.remoting.VirtualChannel$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:31)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
        at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:142)
        at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:114)
        at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
        at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:111)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:3556)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScript(Jenkins.java:3528)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor204.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:188)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2516)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2505)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Script1
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java_io_ObjectOutputStream$defaultWriteObject.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
        at Script1$1.writeObject(Script1.groovy:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest._serialize(UserRequest.java:158)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:167)
        ... 86 more
```

Not sure what am I missing here, anyone has any advice?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I have used a work around for my specific problem, which was to run subversion in the slave. I am now using hudson.FilePath to copy files between master and slave. I have a working example here-http://stackoverflow.com/a/31536895/2485936. Comment if you need further help

Comment: Thanks. But your workaround doesn't work on a slave. 
I was trying to get access to any Jenkins object instances like the `SVNClientManager` on the Slave via groovy but I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: That's true, that's why I do the file operation on the master and then copy the files over to slave. Although not elegant, it just worked for my requirement. Please post if you find a way to do actual remoting.

Comment: I am using Jenkins 2.190.1 and I had the opposite problem with the same script. It fails with "Failed to *deserialize* the Callable object". I have created an issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59778.

Answer (score 0):

you should upgradle to the latest version

it works for me

https://gist.github.com/jiahut/cd4949a2c4d2b43ca9732e20829baa59

the script result is blew :

```
Jenkins version: 2.171
Groovy version: 2.4.12
```