# How to execute groovy/java code in the context of a jenkins-pipeline slave node block?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In this snippet:

```
stage('build') {
    node ('myslave') {
        git(url: 'git@hostname:project.git')
        println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName())
    }
}
```

The git step is executed correctly and checks out code **into node's workspace**.
But why do I get Masters' hostname when executing the second command?

For example, this is not working also in the context of a `node() {}`

```
new File("${WORKSPACE}).listFiles()
```

Which does not actually iterate the `${WORKSPACE}` folder

Comment: In general, `sh` steps should be used for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

All Groovy code in an Pipeline script is executed on the master. I'm been unable to find any way to execute a generic groovy code on the slave, not due to lack of functionality in the Jenkins core, but problems with Pipeline groovy and serialisation of objects. [Found this related question which addresses remoting in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446468/jenkins-remoting-callable-on-slave-using-groovy).

It is however possible to do file operations on the slave side, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250567/using-filepath-to-access-workspace-on-slave-in-jenkins-pipeline/42018578#42018578) for example how you can access files on the slave.